# How do I return positive responses other than HTTP 200 OK with Luracast Restler?

Tags: php, api, rest

I understand that Restler automatically returns the result of my method with the HTTP Status code 200 (OK) and if I want to return an error response I use

```
throw new RestException(400); // returns HTTP 400 Bad Request
```

But how do I return a response of say, HTTP 201 Created along with the resulting value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
header("HTTP/1.1 201 Some response");
```

should work

Answer (score 3):

I hit this too and I'm returning success states manually:

```
return(array('success' => array('code' => 201, 'msg' => 'resulting value')));
```

If you want RESTler to handle it for you:

```
throw new RestException(201, 'resulting value');
```

but that will be returned under the "error" state:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 201,
        "msg": "resulting value"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hit the same issue. The first code block looks reasonable, although it's "manual".

Answer (score 3):

As of RESTLER 3, you can set an alternate positive response code in the Doc Comments above your API Method. For example, the below Doc Comment sets a DELETE route with a return status of 204 (as long as you don't throw a RESTException)

```
/**
 * Delete an Attribute
 * @status 204
 * @url DELETE {eventTicketId}/registration/{eventTicketRegistrationId}/attribute/{attributeId}
 */

function deleteTicketRegistrationAttribute($eventTicketId,$eventTicketRegistrationId,$attributeId)
{

}
```